# Get method name with class name by regex expression

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I have a .cs file which contain following code

```
namespace Automate
{
    class Class1
    {
        public string GetString
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        private bool flag1;
        private bool flag2;
        public void Method(bool param1)
        {
            bool flag = false;
        }
    }
    class Class2
    {
        private bool flag1;
        private bool flag2;
        public void Method(bool param1)
        {
            bool flag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want a Regex Expression which returns each method name ,Property name and global variable with its associated class name and namespace.

Can any one tell me any possible solution or Idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Sayse no, I think he means that he reads from the .cs file and so it's a text data.

Comment: Instead of rewriting half a compiler (or parser at least) why don't you just compile it and use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) on the result?

Comment: I don't want to use reflection, i want to do it by Regex expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as @volpav writes, this kind of usage of regex isn't recommended... But I have created a regex that matches some of your expectations. However this is something I have just pulled together in a rush, and I'm very very confident that it there are many people here that can write code that won't be matched. I can only give you a ground to start from, and then you'll have to figure it out from there. (For instance this will not match a function without any access modifiers, that you'll have to sort out)

Anyway this is my suggestion:

`\s*(static)?\s*(public|private)\s*\w+\s*(\w+)\s*(\(\s*\w*(,?\s*\w+)*\))?`

However, I can really recommend you to use the page: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to help you with the regex!

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions for this kind of analysis. You won't be able to build a robust parser (e.g. methods returning the results with fully-qualified type names, generic method returning generic types, etc. But of course all this depends on the specifics of your task).

If you're developing under .NET 4.5, I'd use [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) - it's the perfect tool for this kind of job and it's relatively easy to get started with. Another approach would be to write a simple [tokenizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization) and gather class structure with it.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there may be times where you need to extract information from source code before compile time (so reflection is out), and you may not be able to use Roslyn.  In particular, when you need the information in a T4 template to generate code that will be compiled alongside the source code.

I've written the following (not tested just yet) for VB.NET in order to extract class names and property names and types into named capture groups:

```
Static regexClassName As New Regex("(?<=^[^']*\bclass\s)(?<class>\b\w*)", RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
Static regexProperty As New Regex("(?<=^[^']*\bproperty\s)(?<property>\b\w*)\s[Aa]s\s(?<type>\b\w*)", RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

These regular expressions shouldn't match commented-out code.

The C# equivalent should look something like `(?<=^[^/]*\bclass\s)(?<class>\b\w*)` to get the Class name.

Comment: Another downside of the RegEx approach: You can tell if your class inherits from another specific class, but it's not so easy to tell if your class inherits from a class that inherits from a specific class.  This is why I'd like to see Roslyn 1.0.